# Making a URL dynamic so it doesn't need to be changed on migration between environments

Tags: html, analytics

I need to make the origin of a URL dynamic so that when I migrate from one environment to another, e.g. dev to production, I don't need to carry out any post migration steps which would potentially invalidate any testing.

For Example

I have a link set up in my development environment that (say dev.mysite) along the lines of page.DEV.mysite/parameter1/parameter2.

When I migrate to production (prod.mysite), I need the link to automatically change to page.PROD.mysite/parameter1/parameter2.

the only option I have is to use a URL and cannot do any java scripting within the screens I am working on so hoping that it can somehow be parameterised somehow.

I have looked at developer options but can't seem to get the URL in there. I can use logical SQL but the URL isn't part of the SQL query.

I have looked to see if I can use the const function to return the URL as part of a query but this doesn't exist within the software.

Comment: I think you need to provide more information about the application and environment. Are you using PHP? Are you using plain HTML?